# Can't retrieve object properties after copying

Tags: typescript, angular-material2, angular5

I'm trying to pass data from one component to another in angular, with the second component being displayed as a Material Dialog.  Before the object is passed, it behaves as expected, but when I pass it, I loose access to everything but the first property.

The passing class:

```
displayDetail(i) {
     let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PartDetailComponent, {
     width: '90%',
     data: { part: this.partList.find(x => x.partNumber = i) , id: i }
   });

   dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
   console.log('The dialog was closed');
  });
}
```

the receiving class

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PartDetailComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Part) {
    if (data == undefined) {
      console.log("Bad data.  Closing modal.")
    }
    else {
      this.part = data;
      console.log(data);  // object now only has id
      console.log(this.part); // identical to data
      console.log(this.part.id); // displays id
      console.log(this.part.description); // undefined
      console.log(data.description); // undefined
    }
}
```

I'm new to angular and somewhat of a novice with typescript, but this doesn't seem like it should be happening.  What the heck is going on?

EDIT: In case the Part class is relevant:

```
export class Part {
  id: number; // assuming there's an ID unique of partNumber or sku
  title: string;
  partNumber: number;
  description: string;
  leadTime: number; 
  weight: number;
  sku: number;
  pictureUrl: string;
  inventory: number;
  inStock: boolean;
  isOrderable: boolean;
  instructions: string;
}
```

Comment: What about `data.part.description`?

Comment: doesn't recognize that data.part exists because I explicitly told it to expect a part object not an object that has a part property.  See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documenting this since I feel like there's far too little documentation around angular things and this is a fun gotcha.

The conflict was between what kind of object I was passing and what kind of object I was receiving.

I was sending:

```
data: { part: this.partList.find(x => x.partNumber = i) , id: i }
```

Which obviously is an object that contains a part and an id.

I was trying to receive a Part:

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PartDetailComponent>,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Part) {
```

So when I changed the receiving object to any, I was then able to access data.part and use it properly.

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PartDetailComponent>,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
```

This is more of a transpiling gotcha, as there's no intercomponent type checking (like there would be in most cases in a compiled language like C#).  The transpiler doesn't check, nor does it care, that components connected to one another might be passing the 'wrong' kind of data and javascript just does what it can with what it receives.